# DispatcherTimer to run randomly in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I need to do some stuff in my application while application is running. I put it in dispatcher to work withing given time intervals. But now I want to randomized things.

I want to set random time intervals.

```
dTSettings.Tick += new EventHandler(dTSettings_Tick);
dTSettings.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, SetRandomTimer(), 0);
dTSettings.Start();
```

how to do that?

Comment: "But now I want to randomized things" - you'll need to provide more details than that. Think carefully about *exactly* what you mean by "randomized" here. There are lots of different potential meanings.

Comment: Can't you simply trigger the timer "often enough" and then randomly decide if you want to do something in the event handler?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private DispatcherTimer _timer = new DispatcherTimer();
private Random rand = new Random();

public void InitAndStartTimer()
{
    _timer.Tick += dispatcherTimer_Tick;
    _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(rand.Next(1, 10)); // From 1 s to 10 s
    _timer.Start();
}

private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _timer.Interval = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(rand.Next(1, 10)); // From 1 s to 10 s
    // Do your work.
}
```